# Disco Diffusion 5.2. NameError: name 'frames_skip_steps' is not defined. What to do?

Tags: python

Disco Diffusion 5.2. NameError: name 'frames_skip_steps' is not defined. What to do? New to all of this.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Also, the bit of code that does show in the image doesn't show your imports, so it's unclear where you expected `frame_skip_steps` to come from exactly?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to be more descriptive and share some information that people can copy and paste. I think your issue can be resolved by running everything again. You likely installed some cells for the first time and the server disconnected. Run everything again it should work.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32207053)

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the entire Disco Diffusion folder from the Google Drive. It seemed to work for me. I can't offer a technical explanation because I have no idea!